# Securely storing user's balance in Parse data browser

Tags: java, android, parsing, stripe-payments

I am building an application in which a user will be receiving money and sending money using Stripe. I would like to hold the users balance in Parse's data browser and let it accumulate until the user wants to withdraw their money. Is it secure to make an object to hold the balance and then just continue to update that object in the future? I am afraid of an intruder possibly decompiling my app in the future and them somehow change their balance to a much higher number and withdrawing in the future.

Thanks ahead of time!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it will be secure if you have the user log in to access it.  You'll need to create a parse user and associate the sensitive data with an ACL containing that user.  Look into sessions and expiring sessions and so on to make sure you prompt for a login at appropriate times.